# What is the best way of threading while using c++ to create windows form application in visual studio?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to create a windows form application which waits for a message from a client using socket.

But the program is shown as not responding in the task manager.

So in order to avoid this i m planning to use another thread to run the wait process. But visual studio 2010 has limited threading option while developing in c++

Pls help

Comment: *visual studio 2010* cannot decide your threading options.

Comment: Umm... this kinda might get closed due to being off-topic. Asking for a general best way of doing something is not good. But Ima give it a comment, 1st I'd use something that supports c++11 and use  the standard's way. Then I would probably choose boost closely followed by posix. Lastly, Windows SDK, unless you need something specific, that needs it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::thread` is [not supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh920526.aspx) in VisualStudio 2010. You can use any other mean of threading, like [`boost::thread`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread.html) (free and opensource) or [`just::thread`](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/) (commercial) depending on your needs.

Personally, I would go for `boost::thread`, unless late conversion to c++11 were needed, in which case I would use `just::thread`, which is `std` compliant. Both options are terribly easy to get up and running and basic tasks are accomplished with no effort.

I don't have much information about [`boost::thread`'s C++11 compliance](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/compliance.html#thread.compliance.cpp11). Notice that the concept are common to the two libraries

Answer (score 1):

There is no limitation for threading in MSVC++. You can use [`CreateThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or `boost::thread`, `just::thread` or even `std::thread` (if it supports) as your requirement.

You can create a thread for waiting to receive network packets and make free the main thread for windows messages.

[image]

Comment: Just be sure that the communication between the two threads is race-condition free. Writing to the socket can be done directly from the GUI thread, and use Custom Events to go from the socket thread to the GUI thread.

Answer (score 0):

This [Microsoft Developer Network article Safe and Simple Multithreading in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951089.aspx) should provide you the gateway to understanding.  There is quite a bit of documentation as well as a sample program.

The article describes the actual problem you are running into, your main message loop is being halted due to the socket read.

Another possible way of doing this is to use non-blocking sockets and to use the `select()` function to check if there is anything to read on the socket before you try to do a socket read.

Also take a look at the following resources.

Code Project [Threads with Windows Forms Controls in Managed C++](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12740/Threads-with-Windows-Forms-Controls-in-Managed-C).

statckoverflow question [C++ Multithreading with Visual Studio 2010 forms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671221/c-multithreading-with-visual-studio-express-2010-forms-application) which contains a link to additional material.